# Npm Run Dev errores con Laravel Mix

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, laravel-mix

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.6 y VUE.

Al ejecutar NPM RUN DEV tengo problemas en consola que no logro resolver. Ya intenté creando un nuevo proyecto y pasando mis archivos a ese nuevo pero el error persiste.

Actualicé NODE, e intenté todo esto:

Consola como Administrador - Windows.

**Eliminé carpeta node_modules y reinstalé con npm install save**. No solucionó nada.

> Eliminé carpeta node_modules, limpié caché de node, instalé cross-env
>   de esta forma: npm install --global cross-env. Y después ejecute la
>   instalación npm install --no-bin-links.
>
> Eliminé carpeta node_modules, limpié caché de node, eliminé
>   package-lock.json, instalé npm install --global cross-env y npm
>   install --no-bin-links.

Pero nada de esto ha funcionado. Adjunto captura del error en consola:

[image: Error]

Comment: Prueba estos [pasos](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072#issuecomment-319401164)

Comment: @BlackSheep justo lo hice amigo en mi publicación  lo comenté

Comment: `cross-env` lo tienes en `devDependencies` listado? Porque veo que lo estás instalando globalmente... Para instalarlo en tu proyecto `npm -i cross-env --save-dev`

Comment: Pega dos detalles muy importantes: Tu configuración del package.json + tu node y npm version. Te ayudaremos muchísimo mejor.